# Why does grep output lines that seemingly don't match the expression?

Tags: grep

Why does grep output lines that seemingly don't match the expression?

As mentioned in [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338423/why-does-grep-output-lines-that-seemingly-dont-match-the-expression#comment597913_338423) this behaviour may be caused by a bug.

I am aware different locales affect character order but I thought the -o output below confirms this is not a problem here but I was wrong. Adding LC_ALL=C gives expected output.

I had [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338456/why-is-output-for-grep-o-the-same-with-or-without-lc-all-c) after I saw locales affected the output.

```
[aa@bb grep-test]$ cat input.txt
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee

[aa@bb grep-test]$ LC_ALL=C grep -o [A-Z] input.txt
C
C
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep -o [A-Z] input.txt
C
C
[aa@bb grep-test]$ LC_ALL=C grep [A-Z] input.txt
CC cc
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep [A-Z] input.txt
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
[aa@bb grep-test]$





[aa@bb tmp]$ cat test
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee

[aa@bb tmp]$ grep [A-Z] test
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
[aa@bb tmp]$ grep -o [A-Z] test
C
C
[aa@bb tmp]$ grep -E [A-Z] test
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
[aa@bb tmp]$ grep -n [A-Z] test
1:aa bb
2:CC cc
3:dd ee
[aa@bb tmp]$ echo [A-Z]
[A-Z]
[aa@bb tmp]$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.6.3
...
[aa@bb tmp]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
...
[aa@bb grep-test]$ command -v grep
/bin/grep
[aa@bb grep-test]$ rpm -q -f $(command -v grep)
grep-2.6.3-6.el6.x86_64
[aa@bb grep-test]$ echo grep [A-Z] input.txt | xxd
0000000: 6772 6570 205b 412d 5a5d 2069 6e70 7574  grep [A-Z] input
0000010: 2e74 7874 0a                             .txt.    
[aa@bb grep-test]$ cmd='grep [A-Z] input.txt'; echo $cmd | xxd; eval $cmd
0000000: 6772 6570 205b 412d 5a5d 2069 6e70 7574  grep [A-Z] input
0000010: 2e74 7874 0a                             .txt.
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
[aa@bb grep-test]$ xxd input.txt
0000000: 6161 2062 620a 4343 2063 630a 6464 2065  aa bb.CC cc.dd e
0000010: 650a 0a                                  e..
[aa@bb grep-test]$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52054/discussion-on-question-by-brendan-why-does-grep-output-lines-that-seemingly-don).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your locale collation rules being very ... helpful.

Try it with

```
LC_ALL=C grep [A-Z] input.txt
```

to test that idea.

I have

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_NUMERIC=C
```

in my shell startup to avoid this kind of trouble while still getting my unicode goodness.

Comment: It seems that the locale collation rules sort `AaBbCcDdEe...Zz`, which means that `[A-Z]` contains all uppercase letters and almost all lowercase letters except `z`.

Comment: Depends on the locale, in `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` the sorting is aAzZ and the grep only matches the A and Z.

Comment: * it also matches the stuff between, the point being `[A-Z]` doesn't match any lowercase, its range-matching logic is not the same as its sorting logic

Comment: As mentioned in [another comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338423/why-does-grep-output-lines-that-seemingly-dont-match-the-expression#comment597913_338423) this behaviour may be caused by a bug.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug.  [Collation sorting and matching are ticklish tasks](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Searching), that can depend on locale, user preference, and purpose.  If grep wants to interpret `[A-Z]` as a case-sensitive search it's completely correct to not match lowercase letters regardless of where they might fall in the sort order.

Comment: The thing is it looks like the matching strings other than capital letters are empty strings. It still does not seem to match the lower case letters.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'A' isn't latin 'A':

```
cmd='grep [A-Z] test'; echo $cmd | xxd; eval $cmd
0000000: 6772 6570 205b ***41***2d 5a5d 2074 6573 740a  grep [A-Z] test.
CC cc


cmd='grep [А-Z] test'; echo $cmd | xxd; eval $cmd
0000000: 6772 6570 205b ***d090*** 2d5a 5d20 7465 7374  grep [..-Z] test
0000010: 0a                                       .
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
```

Comment: added output to question. When I type A, it looks like ASCII 41

Comment: I've edited my post and updated command to check result, please check with new command. Also please show content of your test file with `xxd test`.

Comment: Done. Correct me if I'm wrong but this doesn't seem to be my problem. May be for others though so good answer

Answer (score 2):

Unable to replicate with either BSD or GNU `grep`:

BSD:

```
$ cat test
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
$ grep [A-Z] test
CC cc
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

GNU:

```
$ cat test
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
$ grep [A-Z] test
CC cc
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: You should be able to reproduce it with GNU grep 2.6.3 and some earlier versions