# Why is output for `grep -o` the same with or without LC_ALL=C?

Tags: grep, locale

Why is output for `grep -o` the same with or without LC_ALL=C? There is a difference for grep with no flags for me as expected but there's no difference for `grep -o`. Does `grep -o` always use LC_ALL=C or something else?

```
[aa@bb grep-test]$ cat input.txt
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee

[aa@bb grep-test]$ LC_ALL=C grep -o [A-Z] input.txt
C
C
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep -o [A-Z] input.txt
C
C
[aa@bb grep-test]$ LC_ALL=C grep [A-Z] input.txt
CC cc
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep [A-Z] input.txt
aa bb
CC cc
dd ee
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.6.3
...
[aa@bb src]$ ./grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.27
...
[aa@bb src]$ ./grep [A-Z] ../../test
CC cc
[aa@bb src]$ 
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep a input.txt
aa bb
[aa@bb grep-test]$ grep C input.txt
CC cc
[aa@bb grep-test]$ locale
LANG=en_IE
LC_CTYPE="en_IE"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IE"
LC_TIME="en_IE"
LC_COLLATE="en_IE"
LC_MONETARY="en_IE"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IE"
LC_PAPER="en_IE"
LC_NAME="en_IE"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IE"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IE"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IE"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IE"
LC_ALL=
[aa@bb grep-test]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
...
[aa@bb grep-test]$ xxd input.txt
0000000: 6161 2062 620a 4343 2063 630a 6464 2065  aa bb.CC cc.dd e
0000010: 650a 0a                                  e..
[aa@bb grep-test]$ cat -A input.txt
aa bb$
CC cc$
dd ee$
$
[aa@bb grep-test]$
```

Comment: I think what has to be going on is that the line ending character of the file input.txt is not being recognized as such.  I'm not sure why else `grep [A-Z] input.txt` would match every line of input.txt.  How was input.txt created?  What happens if you try to match another line, say `grep a input.txt'?  Does that also match every line of input.txt?

Comment: grep 2.6.3 is pretty old. Can you try with a newer version so as to discriminate between a (already fixed) bug in grep, and a legitimate functioning due to specificities of your environment?

Comment: It was created with cat > input.txt and I typed into the terminal.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that whatever is matching in the first case is zero-length: compare for example `grep '[A-Z]\|' test` (every line matches the empty pattern; every line is printed) versus `grep -o '[A-Z]\|' test` (matching portions consisting of empty strings do not appear in the output).

Comment: @xhienne locale issue for grep with no flags seems to be fixed in latest version. Latest version behaves as expected without need for LC_ALL=C. So I suppose there was a bug. Any idea when this was fixed, what the bug was or how to find out either of those?

Comment: Well the `Bug fixes` section of the `NEWS` file for GNU grep 2.8 rather cryptically notes that *"grep's interpretation of range expression is now more consistent with that of other tools.  [bug present since multi-byte character set support was introduced in 2.5.2, though the steps needed to reproduce it changed in grep-2.6]"* - maybe that gives you a lead?

Comment: @steeldriver Good guess. I should have went back to the man page:        -o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (**non-empty**) parts of a matching  line

Comment: @steeldriver Yes that could be the bug. I might have a look at that version

Comment: It is fixed in 2.8

Comment: It is also fixed in 2.7, the next release after 2.6.3